# How to determine the default executable for a specific file format?

Tags: python, cross-platform

Is there a way to do this, just by relying on the file's extension?

For example: `os.system(filepath)` opens the given filepath using the default application, but what is the **executable's** filepath?

Comment: And what do you mean by 'default executable'? The program the OS will use when you doubleclick a given file?

Comment: Exactly the default app the OS is using to launch specific a filetype (like double clicking in a windowed interface).

Comment: [Get file association in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5537599)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: That might be a way to do it, but isn't there something more python based instead of OS API requests? Anyways, thanks a lot!

Comment: It is the OS that holds the information, so you'll have to query an OS API one way or another.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can write assumptions into your program, which is what all developers do to handle these formats. It doesn't matter what extension a file has, it can be used as a format regardless.

Take for example an XML file. If you take that XML data and put it into a .txt file, or simply rename the .xml file to .txt, reading from that file and parsing the data within will still render XML formats.