# How to fix python file association/settings?

Tags: python, canopy

I had installed Canopy Python a while ago, which changed my python file associations and removed the edit with IDLE option from python. I've uninstalled Canopy, and re-installed python many times, but the file associations and edit with IDLE were still missing. I've tried looking up solutions, but nothing has worked so far.

I've tried to completely remove python and fresh install, but still no result.

Answer (score 0):

make 2 .bat files on desktop:

**install.bat**

```
assoc .py=PyScript
ftype PyScript="%LOCALAPPDATA%\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe" %1
```

**uninstall.bat**

```
ftype PyScript=
assoc .py=
```

by running uninstall first with admin privileges should have .py released after you uninstall the old python ;
run the new python version you downloaded and run install

to verify it create on desktop

**hello.py**

```
print('Python:Hello, World!')
```

open a new cmd  type cd desktop  and hit  key
type now hello.py and hit the same  key and should work: you should see the result of the script