# Internal Server Error while running Python Program

Tags: python, windows, apache, xampp, cgi

I am running XAMPP on windows, and trying to run following python code and it is giving 500 Internal Server Error, when I checked error log it says:AH01909: [www.example.com:443:0](http://www.example.com:443:0) server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name, [cgi:error] [pid 17416:tid 1836] (OS 5)Access is denied.  : [client ::1:1031] AH01223: couldn't spawn child process: C:/xampp/htdocs/test.py

My code:
#!C:/Users/Sravani/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32
print ("Content-type:text/html\n")
print ("")
print ("")
print ("First CGI Program")
print ("")
print ("")
print ("

### Hello

")
print ("")
print ("")

can anyone help me in this regard

Answer (score 0):

You should probably check if it's the wrong location

> #!C:/Users/Sravani/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32

Comment: even I tried #!c:\users\sravani\AppData\Local\Programs\Phython\Python38-32

Comment: here where my python was saved

Answer (score 0):

use install.bat i posted here :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71735909/5781320

in windows 10 x64+ apache + php 8.1  +...    and python associated correctly i have in my htdocs a folder test where i have 2 files:

**index.php**

```
<?php

// Highest priority
proc_nice(-20);

//echo shell_exec('index.rb');
//system('index.rb');

echo shell_exec('index.py');
//system('index.py');


?>
```

and **index.py**  :

**print('Python:Hello, World!')**

by calling in browser http://localhost/test/ i got running the python script without calling it cgi  (!#...)

i let in place the comments you read ..

```
//echo shell_exec('index.rb');
//system('index.rb');
```

cause i have even ruby and the index.rb and they running both ! (i am not python user and neither ruby but i usually for a while i try both of them -even golang to see what's new ..)

the **index.rb**

```
#puts "Content-type: text/html\r\n"
puts "Ruby:Hello World" + "<br>"

time1 = Time.new
puts "Current Time : " + time1.inspect + "<br>"

# Time.now is a synonym:
time2 = Time.now
puts "Current Time : " + time2.inspect + "<br>"
```

in ruby is no need to associate nothing you have already all done(in case you corrupt that you fix with this)